# Dynamic require in Webpack at build time

Tags: webpack

Considering there's Webpack config

```
...
entry: {
    'bundle-with-dependency-a': 'common-entry.js',
    'bundle-with-dependency-b': 'common-entry.js'
},
resolve: {
    alias: {
        'dep-a': ...,
        'dep-b': ...
    },
},
```

and I would expect in `common-entry.js` something like this:

```
require('dep-' + entryName.slice(-1));
```

I.e. I want to provide the definition for particular require from config.

The problem is that there may be more than 2 dependency options, I avoid copypasting. And I'm about to do this at build time, instead of requiring the chunks with JSONP.

How can this require be made dynamic?

The only option I've got here is to have different configuration for each dep, but this requires to make multiple Webpack passes instead of single. Not very convenient.

Answer (score 6):

Using the [`imports-loader`](https://github.com/webpack/imports-loader):

`webpack.config.js`

```js
{
  entry: {
    'bundle-with-dependency-a': 'imports?depName=>"dep-a"!./common-entry.js',
    'bundle-with-dependency-b': 'imports?depName=>"dep-b"!./common-entry.js',
  },
  // ...
}
```

The `depName` variable will then be exposed to the `common-entry.js` module.

Comment: It looks good, I'm not sure that I even knew that loaders can be used in entries. I wonder if there are ways other than 'imports', there can be several deps with same ('a' or 'b') prefix which will make loader query string quite long.

Comment: Then I'd recommend either looking at making your own loader, or creating a function that generates the query string for you. An example: `imports({ depName: 'dep-a' }) + './common-entry.js'`

Comment: Yes, constructing query is good enough. I wonder if there are other roundabouts, e.g. `context` and ContextReplacementPlugin (Webpack documentation is ridiculously lacking on their potential use).